# Adding values to multi-value field and displaying them

Tags: xpages

I have 3 multi-value fields and I have already inserted values in them. All of the fields are Text type, edible. What I'm trying to do is that I want to add functionality in xpages, so that I can add new values to those fields. 
Here's what I got so far:

The code that triggers on the save button:

```
var statuss = document1.getItemValue("statuss");
var stat_vec:java.util.Vector = document1.getItemValue("statuss_update");
stat_vec.add(statuss);
document1.replaceItemValue("statuss_update", stat_vec);

var vards = session.getEffectiveUserName();
var vards_vec:java.util.Vector = document1.getItemValue("name_update");
vards_vec.add(vards);
document1.replaceItemValue("name_update", vards_vec);

var laiks = session.createDateTime("Today");
var laiks_vec:java.util.Vector = document1.getItemValue("time_update");
laiks_vec.add(laiks);
document1.replaceItemValue("time_update", laiks_vec);

document1.save();
```

The code that I have atteched to the computedField, where the values are displayed from the 3 multi value fields + it refreshes when I insert new values:

```
var x = document1.getItemValue("statuss_update");
    var y = document1.getItemValue("name_update");
    var z = document1.getItemValue("time_update");


    var html = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type = \"text/css\" href=\"test.css\"></head><table id=\"tabula\">";

    for (i = 0 ; i < x.size()-1; i++){
        html= html + "<tr><td>" + x[i] +  "</td><td>" + y[i] + "</td><td>" +z[i] + "</td></tr>";
        }
    html = html + "</table>";
```

I can insert the values and they get displayed in the HTML table but the problem is with saving the edits. Whenever I try to save the document (I have a save button that has save document event attached to it) I get the error:

> Could not save the document 1B06 NotesException: Unknown or
>   unsupported object type in Vector

As far as I understand I'm trying to savesomething in a field, where the values type is not supported. Can anyone give me a hint what am I doing wrong or where to look for the problem? Been stuck with this for a pretty long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this part?

```
var statuss = document1.getItemValue("statuss");
var stat_vec:java.util.Vector = document1.getItemValue("statuss_update");
stat_vec.add(statuss);
```

It looks like you're getting the `statuss` item's values (potentially a Vector??) and adding it to the Vector for `statuss_update`. If it's definitely just one value, `getItemValueString()` would work better.

I'm nnot sure if this is right, but you mention all fields are Text type, but it looks like you're passing a DateTime to the third one.

It might be worth analysing the contents of the Vectors before it's doing the save, just to make sure they contain what you expect.

Comment: Hello Paul

I replaced the .getItemValue with .getItemValueString

About the date- i created a lib and used "import *libname*" in to the code, which gives me a string of the date.

Also- is there some kind of debbuger that I could use to see what each vector contains?

Comment: Just fixed the problem, thank you. It was because of the date, I didn't realize that I didn't get a string value, which caused the error. But i'd still like to know is there a way to debug the code?

Comment: Methods like that only throw the error on the save() method, not the replaceItemValue(). Even with Reader access you can call replaceItemValue() as much as you want and it won't throw an error until you call save() - and developers have used this to their benefit. As part of the OpenNTF Domino API team, we've discussed benefits / impacts of doing those kinds of checks, but haven't agreed to make a change to how the core Domino API does things as yet.